# What should be the delay to be given for reading accelerometer

Tags: accelerometer

I have five accelrometer sensors (MMA 7361) connected to the analog channels of Arduino Duemilanove. I am using the following code to read the data. (I am reading from only one axis from each sensor.)

```
#include <avr/io.h>
#include <avr/wdt.h>

int sensorValue = 0; // value read from the pot

void setup() 
{
    Serial.begin(9600); // initialize serial communications at 9600 bps:
}

void loop() 
{
    // read the analog values:

    int i=1;

    Serial.print("ACS#");

    for(i=0;i<5;i++)
    {

        sensorValue = analogRead(i);
        Serial.print(sensorValue);
        Serial.print("#");

        delay(10);
    }

    Serial.println("");

}
```

I am using a delay of 10 after reading each sensor. What should the value of the delay I should be using after reading one sensor to get the correct values from the sensors?

Comment: Why do you need *any* delay?

Comment: No delay is needed. Note however that the serial communication might not be able to keep up. If that happens your Serial.print calls will block/delay until the TX-buffer is no longer full. No big deal, but might be useful to know.

Comment: What are you trying to do with the data? This will help us give you an answer about sample rates

Answer (score 1):

A delay is not needed.

What can be more beneficial, though, is making a dummy reading between each real reading.  This gives the ADC more of a chance to settle on the right reading without the Sample and Hold capacitor being influenced by the previous reading.

The simplest way is just to duplicate your `analogRead` line so it's done twice.

Comment: what is the time required for the ADC to settle on the right reading?

Comment: You'll find that kind of information in the datasheet. Cross-reference that with the analogRead() code to see what the current settings are.

Comment: @ukg You don't need to wait for the ADC to settle for any of the readings, each pin uses a different ADC, and they are continuously tracking the input.